# Eclipse Git Commit Signing - "Failed to parse secret key file"

Tags: eclipse, gnupg, jgit

I recently decided to start using **Git** with **Eclipse** to commit changes to **GitHub**, and after some struggling I got it to work. However, I have been unable to **sign my commits** in Eclipse. Here's what happens to produce the error:

I have the lock icon selected and attempt to commit changes.

[image: Commit with Lock Icon Selected]

I get the prompt to enter the passphrase for my `user.signingkey`.

[image: Prompt for Passphrase]

I copy and paste the passphrase in for the key, and I get the following error.

[image: Error Message]

To debug/fix this issue, I have tried:

- Creating and using a new key with a shorter passphrase (<16 chars)
- Typing in the passphrase manually
- Adding signing configuration to the repository itself on top of the global Git config

Nothing that I have tried has fixed the issue or even changed the error message. At this point, I am thinking that I must have messed up something quite simple, or this is an issue with the **latest Eclipse release** (which I am currently running).

Is there something I'm missing or does this look like a bug with Eclipse?

Thanks!

Comment: The error message comes from jgit, the Java implementation used inside egit (Eclipse's version of Git). It's not in Git itself, it's a `gpgFailedToParseSecretKey` error. I updated your tags, but I have no idea why the Java implementation is raising this error.

Comment: @torek So do you think it looks like a possible bug with JGit or Eclipse then? I'd be more than happy to do any testing if you have any ideas. Thanks :)

Comment: If it works in Git but not Egit, I'd guess that the jgit code that attempts to duplicate all the GPG work ... doesn't. But I don't have Eclipse at all; all I can suggest is to see if it works outside Eclipse/Egit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to sign your commits from Eclipse (EGit) you have to set `External GPG` for the general Eclipse settings as described here:

https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/New_and_Noteworthy/5.11#Using_GPG_to_Sign_Commits_and_Tags

Comment: I forgot to respond, but this was the solution to this problem. After changing the "For signing commits and tags use:" option to "External GPG", the signing worked just fine. Thank you!